# TypeError: <Function> takes X positional argument but X were given

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing, python-watchdog

I'm trying to do a continuous monitor of some directories in the system so I used WatchDog API. The function I'm using:

```
def watcher(HRSpath):
    src_path = HRSpath
    event_handler = Handler()
    observer = watchdog.observers.Observer()
    observer.schedule(event_handler, path=src_path, recursive=True)
    observer.start()
    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()
    observer.join()
```

The events I'm interested in is delete only as I'm overriding another method from WatchDog class:

```
class Handler(watchdog.events.PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    def on_deleted(self, event):
        print("Watchdog received deleted event - % s." % event.src_path)
```

Using the main function:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    pth = "/home/abd/Downloads/"
    pth2 = "/home/abd/Desktop/"

    Proc1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=watcher, args=(pth))
    Proc2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=watcher, args=(pth2))
    Proc1.start()
    Proc2.start()
```

The code always yields an error saying whenever I use Multiprocessing/Threading class:

> Process Process-1: Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in
> _bootstrap
> self.run()   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs) TypeError: watcher() takes 1 positional argument but 20 were given Process Process-2:
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 315, in
> _bootstrap
> self.run()   File "/usr/lib/python3.9/multiprocessing/process.py", line 108, in run
> self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs) TypeError: watcher() takes 1 positional argument but 18 were given
>
> Process finished with exit code 0

However, if I changed the main function code to call on watcher() method on a single path it works with no issue:

```
 if __name__ == '__main__':
        pth = "/home/abd/Downloads/"
        watcher(pth)
```

The full code is available [Here](https://pastebin.com/rPRkKsWs)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one of the pitfalls in python: you need to add a comma after `pth` :-)

```
Proc1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=watcher, args=(pth, ))
```

Your code passes 20 (resp 18) characters as arguments, and not one string.

Comment: Yep, that did the trick :), many thanks to you Andreas.